# cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'transaction-manager' is not allowed to appear in element 'tx:annotation-driven

Tags: java, spring, jsp

[image]

trying to deploy war file:
getting this error in spring_persistance.xml  line 31 :

[image]

Comment: Line 31 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring_persistence.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'transaction-manager' is not allowed to appear in element 'tx:annotation-driven'.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 31; columnNumber: 58; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'transaction-manager' is not allowed to appear in element 'tx:annotation-driven'.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't post code, errors as images as they become unreadable. Please use plain text with proper code formatting.